# Are Firebase snapshot listeners detached when the object they are attached to is deinitialized?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, say I have a listener attached to a class instance called `MyObject`. If `MyObject` is set to `nil`, are all listeners associated with it detached too or do I need to manually detach the listeners before deinitializing `MyObject`?

Edit: Here's a rough example of what I'm talking about:

MyObject definition :

```swift
class MyObject {
   var listener: ListenerRegistration?

   func getData() {
      self.listener = self.db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { 
        (querySnapshot, err) in ... }
      }
}
```

Implementing Class:

```
class ObjectTwo {
   var ref: MyObject?
}
```

And then later:

```swift
var obj = ObjectTwo(ref: MyObject())
obj.ref!.getData()
obj.ref = nil
```

Is the realtime listener in the `MyObject` instance detached now, or do I need to call `obj.ref!.listener!.remove()` before setting `obj.ref = nil` to properly remove the listener?

Comment: Please edit the question to show code that better illustrates what you are concerned about.

Comment: The answer provided is the answer but I am curious what the use case is here? Why create 10 of the same class of objects all with a listener on the same node? Why not create one listener on that node - I would think that would be much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the code you shared that detaches the listener. If you want to [detach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), you will have to do so explicitly in your code before setting the object reference to nil.